# Images without http or https are not loading in html

Tags: html, image, rendering

I have images uploaded to database but somehow when an editor adds an image via a tool,its added like below:
"//images.***.com/a.jpeg"
So when i try to render the image in my html template with my json source it shows blank. If i manually add http or https to the json attribute in the html itself, it works fine. I am not able to understand why my image is not rendering in html without appending http/s:. I am not a front end developer but i do some light work with html tags but this one is beyond my understanding, any help will be greatly  appreciated.

Comment: Could I see your json export code?

Comment: here: { "GroupId": 4, "Config": { "templateId": "82", "defaultAdTag": "Advertisement", "esp": 1, "thirdPartyLinkTracking": true }, "Name": "test Names", "UrlId": "test-name-var", "ImageUrl": "//images.xyz.com/xyz.jpeg", "Topics": [ ] }

Answer (score 0):

Do you write like this?

```
<img src="_the_link_goes_here_">
```

Comment: something like <img src="{varname}"> Also the thing is when the image has https: appended it works fine